# How to hide column of Gridview when there is no data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to hide the column of gridview dynamically if there is not data.
There is column i.e. Attachment which i want to hide but unfortunately there is something wrong in coding but i am not able to find it
Following is my code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="attengrid" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                        ShowHeader="true" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpName" HeaderText="Emp.Name"></asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DOB" HeaderText="DOB"></asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Qualification" HeaderText="Designation"></asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="HomePlace" HeaderText="Home Town"></asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DOJInGovrService" HeaderText="DOJ In Gov.Service"></asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DOJInSamvarg" HeaderText="DOJ In Samvarg"></asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DOJInCurrentOff" HeaderText="DOJ In Current Off."></asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="CurrentOfficePlace" HeaderText="Current Office"></asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="class" HeaderText="Category"></asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Attachment" HeaderText="Attachment"></asp:BoundField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

following is .aspx.cs

```
 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    dbAccess.execute("select ED.class,ED.CurrentOfficePlace,ED.DOB,ED.DOJInCurrentOff,ED.DOJInGovrService,ED.DOJInSamvarg,ED.EmpName,ED.HomePlace,ED.Qualification, ED.Attachment from tbl_EmplyeesBiodata ED where ED.CurrentOfficePlace='" + ddlCurrentPlacePosting.SelectedItem.Text + "'", DBAccess.SQLType.IS_QUERY);
    DataTable dt = dbAccess.records1();
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Label8.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        lblmsg.Style.Add("display", "block");
        lblmsg.Attributes.Add("class", "success");
        lblmsg.InnerHtml = closediv + "Case Found";
        tdnotice.Style.Add("display", "block");

    }
    else
    {

        lblmsg.Style.Add("display", "block");
        lblmsg.Attributes.Add("class", "error");
        lblmsg.InnerHtml = closediv + "No Case Found";
        tdnotice.Style.Add("display", "none");

    }
}


 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string val = e.Row.Cells[9].ToString();  
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
        {
            GridView1.Columns[9].Visible = false;     
        }

    }
}
```

This code is not working it is still showing the column
please help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. Its analogous to deleting particular columns where people not present in an assembly. It will screw up the formation.

The `GridView` get rendered as a table (HTML). If you *View Source* you can see a table with 10 `td` for each `tr`. That means 10 columns per row. Now, you want to hide one column in some rows conditionally.

Now, if you do not have data in any of the rows at your 10th column, you can hide it. But RowDataBound is not the event for that. Do it after your `GridView1.DataBind()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the Visible property before calling DataBind, then it also reduces ViewState slightly as the values are never populated into invisible columns.

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
// .....
bool isBlank = true;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) { // for each row in the data table
    if (!dr.item("Attachment") == System.DbNull.Value) { // if we find a non null value
        isBlank = false; // show the column in the gridview
        break; // then stop checking for nulls
    }
}
GridView1.Columns(9).Visible = !isBlank;
GridView1.DataBind();
}
```